# Paypal Delayed Chained Payments returns "Internal server error. Please check the server logs for details1"

Tags: paypal, response, delay, payment, chained

The following code returns "Internal server error. Please check the server logs for details1"
The number "1" is response?

I would like to know what is wrong and why I can't get proper response.
Also how to format request to get proper response.
Thanks!

```
$url = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay&actionType=PAY_PRIMARY&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T&clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1&currencyCode=USD&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&memo=Example&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=25.00&receiverList.receiver(0).email=vorgminded@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=5.00&receiverList.receiver(1).email=v_corp@live.com&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: vorhegmindehd_api1.gmail.com",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 5VV5B8M8CAH9ZHEZ",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AiPC9BikCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacA3-z5-u8OUawhrQsZCBMbprk73z7",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T"
    ));



    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $resArr = json_decode($result);
    print_r($result);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Additiona info: (server error logs): `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: vor' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/quickser/public_html/dev/njemac/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()'d code on line 9`

Comment: I am trying to implement this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Off the topic, I'd suggest omitting your api account info, even though it's sandbox and most people are well-intended.

Comment: I don't remember if the payload can be put into the url, because when I did it I always put it into the data field of curl - sorry I don't remember the exact way I used before as I don't have access to my test env at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

### After many hours of investigation, this is the right format of the call (code below)

- however now I am getting the:

> "2015-06-11T06:33:51.784-07:00Failure305229b402fe815743565520003PLATFORMApplicationErrorAuthentication
>   failed. API credentials are incorrect."

- while the API credentials are taken from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/ and are correct

Thanks to all who tried to help. If any suggestion about the new error, please reply. Thanks.

```
$url = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails';


$parameters = 'actionType=PAY&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T&clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1&currencyCode=USD&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&memo=Example&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=25.00&receiverList.receiver(0).email=vorgminded@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=5.00&receiverList.receiver(1).email=v_corp@live.com&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID' => 'quxxxxxxxxxxator_api1.gmail.com',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD' => 'QSH6xxxxxx2CXMW',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE' => 'Al.b0WCW1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxrApDew5IUXWrEqJehMdG.PVMtaC7u',
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT' => 'NV',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'NV',
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T'
));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$resArr = json_decode($result);
print_r($result);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

---

### UPDATE

- for all others with the same problem:

Headers were fromatted in a wrong way, also data type was wrong, the code below executes normal

```
$url = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay';


$parameters = 'actionType=PAY_PRIMARY&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T&clientDetails.ipAddress=143.95.39.52&currencyCode=USD&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&memo=Example&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=25.00&receiverList.receiver(0).email=v_corp-facilitator@live.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=5.00&receiverList.receiver(1).email=v_corp-buyer@live.com&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&returnUrl=http://www.google.com&cancelUrl=http://www.net.hr';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
$headers = array(
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: v_corp-facilitator_api1.live.com',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: MVDUDLUZTHUHFE23',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AmoptyIrmh6lUZc78BeJ.pp5-B1qAG6-LkYRukL6PdAXE1igG0TXwyNh',
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON',
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);





//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$resArr = json_decode($result);
print_r($result);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```